# Using IP (Whitelist) restricted API from a Cloud Platform

Tags: api, proxy, cloud, cloud-hosting, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What is the best solution for calling an API that has an IP whitelist from a cloud platform like AWS Elastic Beanstalk that by it's nature has no fixed IP address?

I've come across this problem a lot recently as more and more applications I manage are being built for cloud hosting platforms. So far the only real option I've come across is creating a file on a static IP hosted server that acts as a proxy to the API requests.

Are there any better solutions out there?